# Spark worker node removed but not gone

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.4

I am using Spark standalone with a master and a single worker just to test. At first I used one worker box but now I decided to use a different worker box. To do this, I stopped the Master that was running, I changed the IP in the conf/slave file, and I ran it again. However the old worker is still loading. when I see the 8080 of the master. Now I see as slaves both the new that I placed in the conf/slaves files and the old one I remove from conf/slaves.

I don't know what to do and have searched about it but no results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but stopped the service, remove the folder, create a new folder, run the service again worked